# How to find latest records randomly in mongodb and node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.products.find().limit( 5 ).skip( _rand() * db.products.count() )
```

This code is random but does not limit 5 every request, [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhImX.png)

Comment: You might want to check out [$sample](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)

Comment: To get a specific number of documents randomly you can also try using the `$rand` aggregate operator.